# jQuery: using $.load to get content, result is formatted like so: \n \n Apply<\/a> \n <\/div>\n \n

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    nextPageURL = nextPage.find('a').attr('href') + '#searchResults';
    searchResults.append('<div class="moreList" />');
    $('.moreList').load(nextPageURL);
    var newHTML = $('.moreList').html().replace(/\s+<\/TD>/g,'');
    $('.moreList').html(newHTML);
```

This is the gist of it. More output looks like this:

```
\n Android application design<\/a> <\/h3>\n

\n

Hourly<\/dt>\n
- Est. Time: Less than 1 week, 10 hrs\/week <\/dd>\n
- Posted <\/span> <\/dd>\n
- 3 Interviews<\/dd>\n <\/dl>\n <\/div> \n
\n \n Apply<\/a> \n <\/div>\n \n
<\/div>\n
```

---

Help, would be awesome!

Comment: That's a problem with the URL that you're loading.

Comment: You're right the URL is a problem. It's pulling in a json query

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but if you're using this syntax :

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

you're definitely missing a space before the `#`.

Comment: adding the space breaks it completely (I know, strange--doesn't follow the jQuery syntax).